# If $T(n)$ implies $T(2n)$, $T(n)$ implies $T(n-5)$ for $n \geq 6$ and $T(1)$ is true, then is $T(n)$ true for all $n$ in natural numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, logic, induction

My reasoning:
From the assumption it follows that for all numbers in form $n = 2^m - 5k$, where $n,m,k$ are some natural numbers  $T(n)$ is true. When $n=5$ then $(5 = 2^m - 5k) \equiv 5(k+1) = 2^m$, therefore $n$ can't equal $5$. Hence we can't conclude (from given assumptions) that $T(n)$ is true for all $n$ in natural numbers. Neither we can say that $T(n)$ is not true for all natural numbers. So my answer would be that we can't tell. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the edited version of the question: no, you can't conclude that $T(n)$ is true for every $n$.

Perhaps the easiest way to show this is to notice that if $T(n)$ is the proposition "$n$ is not a multiple of $5$" then it satisfies all three requirements, but is not true for all natural numbers.

Comment: Really nice! $~$

Comment: Dang!  Couldn't see the forest for the trees!  That's pretty obvious once you *look* for it.  Dang, nice.

Comment: Brilliant! But could you specify to which part is "you can't conclude this" reffering to? I don't know if i understand this correctly. I undestand that we can't conclude that T(n) is true for all natural numbers (that's clear based on your's proof) and we neither can say that T(n) is false fore some n in natural numbers (is that right? Its seams intuitive to me because T(n) is not specified and we can add property like "T(5) is true" and then T(n) is true for all natural n).

Comment: @Paweł yes, that's what I meant, edited. You can't deduce that there's any value for which $T(n)$ is false, since all of the rules are consistent with it always being true.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: consider residue classes modulo $5$ - what can you say about these?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  If $k \equiv 1 \pmod 5$ then $2k \equiv 2 \equiv k + 1 \mod 5$.

If $k\equiv 2 \pmod 5$ then $4k \equiv 8 \equiv 3 \equiv k+1 \pmod 5$.

If $k \equiv 3\pmod 5$ then $8k \equiv 24 \equiv  4 \equiv k+ 1\mod 5$.

if $k \equiv 4 \pmod 5$ then .... dang.

Okay, that's it.  You can't get any multiple of $5$.

If $k= 5m$ and we able to conclude that $T(k)$ were true could only do it by assuming it is true for some $n$ were $k = 2n$ or $k = n-5$.  In either case $n$ must be a multiple of $5$ and we are boot strapping.

Hmmm, I'm not sure how to *formally* order thn $n$ so the we can use a well ordering principal to say there we could deduce all natural numbers there must be a "first" multiple of $5$  and that's contradictory (as there is no order of deduction that we "must" follow). But it *is* clear we can not deduce a multiple of $5$ without first deducing some other multiple of $5$ first.

We can deduce all other numbers though.  (If $k \equiv  4 \pmod 5$ then $4k \equiv 1\equiv k+2 \pmod 5$.)